# AdMob banner shows HTML instead of Ad

Tags: android, admob

Sometimes the AdMob banner in my Android App shows plain HTML code instead of a real Ad. But most of the time it works fine.

[image: Screenshot of Incorrect Ad Banner]

Some Ideas what the reason could be?

Comment: For this to be a good question, you really need to include some code so others might reproduce it. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As @Jonathan727 mentioned, the question is unclear so it cannot be answered exactly. According to my assumption, this might be happening because of the poor Internet connectivity. Not sure though!